# Which process select to remotely debug an ecl dll?

Tags: ecl, adamtridionconnector, adam-connector

I'm using a ecl connector and have a dll. Similar to Flickr Provider.

I know that TcmServiceHost process is used for the ECL. But if I want to remotelly debug my dll, Should I attach to TcmSserviceHost process? It doesn't have my code.

Thanks.

Comment: I would expect it to be triggered in the same process as the Content Manager Explorer: IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [Remote Debugging in Visual Studio Made Easy](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-made-easyish)

Answer (score 0):

While the TcmServiceHost sometimes uses an ECL connector, it's more likely that ECL is triggered and used in the Publisher process. Attaching a debugger to the TcmPublisher.exe process should therefore do the trick.